# Enabled Gutemberg Post Editor Not Showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Im working on wordpress with a sevenhills preinstalled theme. The theme's blog is currently showing classic editor, and i cant switch it to gutemberg. WPBakery is also installed.

Things i've tried:

- Installing Gutemberg
- Making Sure Gutemberg is not disabled on gutemberg settings
- Making Sure Bakery is disabled for posts.

Im pretty sure something must be disabling gutemberg, but not sure what just yet.

Any ideas?

https://childrenofamani.org/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

with WPBakery you probably need to go to :

> WPBakery Page Builder Settings > Role Manager

and enable Gutenberg for the appropriate roles.

[image: WPBakery Page Builder Settings]

Comment: I had disabled bakery roles on posts and even so, gutemberg wont show.

Answer (score 0):

As a intermediate solution, we've started using a gutemberg block bakery provides, that allow us to work gutemberg inside of bakery. It wasnt our idea 100% but its a workaround for now.